# CYCLES does not render the objects in a scene when run on a high performance computing infrastructure with Blender 2.81

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have access to a high performance computing machine where Blender 2.81 is installed. When I try to render a scene with CYCLES, however, the objects in the scene are not rendered and only the background color is visible. The problem does not occur with other render engines and with previous versions of Blender, like the 2.79.

The string I use to render the image is
`blender -b ./file.blend -o ./output -s 1 -F PNG -f 1 -E CYCLES`

Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: A "high performance computing machine" to render a png image? Funny. Make sure the scene renders on any other machine using Blender 2.81 as expected in the first place. Do you get the cube from the default scene?

Comment: Ah ah yes for the moment is only a PNG but the purpose is to use it to render movies of simulations we are performing. I'm using the default cube as test system, that works perfectly on my laptop. It also works with EVEE (always) and with CYCLES on previous Blender versions. The cube disappears also when I set CYCLES as render engine on the HPC GUI (thus not going through the command line), so it really seems a problem of CYCLES on the HPC in that specific Blender version.

Comment: Doesn't really make much sense to me. Test against 2.82+ and set the blend file to cycles so that you don't have to do that via command line. If the error persists, consider to file a bug report.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will report it if it will prove to be impossible to solve.